# Are "To be born out in sth..." and "To bear out..." two different phrases?

Tags: phrase-meaning

**To be born out in sth:**

> To be proven by or evidenced in sth.

"His assertion that the customer was not being entirely truthful was born out in the later events."

[image]
[Alternative link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEhIH.jpg)

**To bear somebody/something out**

> to show that someone is right or that something is true

"The other witnesses will bear me out."

"The other witnesses will bear out what I say."

[bear out phrasal verb - Definition, pictures, pronunciation and usage notes | Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary at OxfordLearnersDictionaries.com:](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/bear-out?q=bear%20out)

They both look alike in meaning.

Is **born** a passive form of some plain infinitive?

What is the plain infinitive of **born**?

To **bear** out [plain infinitive]

To be **bore** out [passive]

To have **borne** out [perfect active]

Comment: Do you have any references for these sentences?

Comment: Sure, I have added references for both.

Comment: The first link doesn't work for me.

Comment: Here is the alternative link http://imgur.com/NtCDFMb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a definition of [bear](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bear). Just be be clear about what the tenses referred to in the entry mean:

> bear - infinitive
>
> bore - simple past
>
> borne or born - past participle.

Regarding the past participle: in British English, **borne** is used with the meaning **bear out**, and **born** is used with the meaning of being born (either a baby or a concept).

I understand that in American English the **born** version can be used for both meanings.

See here for more information about [born vs borne](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/161768/borne-out-of-the-desire).

Comment: And just to be clear: X is borne out by Y is the passive version of Y bears out X.